# Auto-liking my mobile app's FB page when a new user logs in using FB

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

My company is developing a iOS app and will be providing social media log-in options, specifically thru Facebook and Twitter.

I will also have a Facebook account for my mobile app (there won't be a Facebook version for the app, just a regular FB account).

My question is this:

Is it possible to automatically "force" new users of my iOS app to "like" my app's FB page when they log-in thru Facebook?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "force" them to like the FB page. This is against facebooks TOS and there is no API for doing this BUT you can stop them using your app if they havnt liked the page.

Not 100% sure how you would do it in iOS but here is a sample script in PHP that may give you an idea.

```
$this->load->library('facebook');

// Gets the signed request from facebook
$signed_request = $this->facebook->getSignedRequest();

//make sure they like the page before they can continue.
$user_liked = (isset($signed_request['page']['liked'])) ? $signed_request['page']['liked'] : FALSE;

if (!$user_liked) {
    //Add link to you facebook page or automatically redirect them to your FB page
    echo '<a href="YOUR_FB_PAGE">Please like our facebook page before you can use our app</a>';
    die;
}

// Rest of your code
```

Comment: That code doesn't work anymore. Like gating is not allowed and the liked property will always be true

Comment: when did this change? we are still using in one of our apps and I believe to the best of my knowledge it was still working the last I heard.

Comment: It changed like half a year ago